# How to display a new screen value when button is clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a page to add a new user when click into a value on menu bar like an Add option that allows users to input a name, an office number, and a phone number

Here is my code:

```js
let menu = ["View", "Add", "Verify", "Update", "Delete"];

let list = document.getElementById("menuList");

menu.forEach((item) => {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerText = item;
  list.appendChild(li);
});

let users = [
  { name: "Jan", id: "1", number: "111-111-111" },
  { name: "Juan", id: "2", number: "222-222-222" },
  { name: "Margie", id: "3", number: "333-333-333" },
  { name: "Sara", id: "4", number: "444-444-444" },
  { name: "Tyrell", id: "5", number: "555-555-555" },
];

var div = "<div class='infor'>";
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
  div += "<div class='user-informations'>";
  div += "<p>" + users[i].name + "</p>";
  div += "<p>" + users[i].id + "</p>";
  div += "<p>" + users[i].number + "</p>";
  div += "</div>";
}
div += "</div>";
document.getElementById("usersList").innerHTML = div;
```

```html
<div class="contact-container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <ul id="menuList">
      <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/contact-card.png"/> 
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="users" id="usersList">
  </div>
</div>
```

my project:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Is something not working? What's the expected outcome?

Comment: My question is how can I create a function that when I click into Add on the left navbar like in the image the right side page will appear an input to add user and doesn't display user information. And when click into View it will display all user information but won't display input to add user

Comment: This isn't a code-generating site. You are expected to make an attempt and ask specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Paying no attention to style or good software engineering practices:

```js
let usersList = document.getElementById("usersList"),
    addPage = document.getElementById("addPage");

const users = [
  { name: "Jan", id: "1", number: "111-111-111" },
  { name: "Juan", id: "2", number: "222-222-222" },
  { name: "Margie", id: "3", number: "333-333-333" },
  { name: "Sara", id: "4", number: "444-444-444" },
  { name: "Tyrell", id: "5", number: "555-555-555" },
];

function showUsers() {
  usersList.innerHTML = "";
  usersList.style.display = "inline";
  addPage.style.display = "none";
  users.forEach(u => {
    const newUser = document.createElement("p");
    newUser.innerHTML = `${u.id} ${u.name}<br/>${u.number}`;
    usersList.appendChild(newUser);
  })
}

function addOn() {
  usersList.style.display = "none";
  addPage.style.display = "inline";
}

function addUser() {
  const id = document.getElementById("id").value;
  const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  const number = document.getElementById("number").value;
  users.unshift({ name: name, id: id, number: number});
  showUsers();
}

showUsers();
```

```css
.navbar { vertical-align: top; padding-right: 1rem; border-right:solid 1px red }
```

```html
<div class="contact-container">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td class="navbar">
        <ul id="menuList" style="cursor:pointer">
          <img src="https://img.icons8.com/ios-filled/50/000000/contact-card.png" />
          <li onclick="showUsers()">View</li>
          <li onclick="addOn()">Add</li>
          <li>...</li>
        </ul>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="users" id="usersList"></div>
        <div id="addPage" style="display:none">
          Id: <input id="id" size="1"/> Name: <input id="name" /><br/>
          Number: <input id="number" /><br/>
          <button onclick="addUser()">Add</button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

It is not necessary to generate the menu list dynamically unless the menu is really dynamic.

Ask if you need explanation on any of the stuff above.